# Error on API call through jQuery, but the data is returned through browser request

Tags: javascript, json, http, http-headers

I am having the following problem. 
I want to take JSON data from the following URL, which works if you click on it: https://api.edmunds.com/api/vehicle/v2/mercedes-benz/models?state=used&view=basic&fmt=json&api_key=334vr68yy9eb4chec2t4hh7s

My code is this:

```
$.getJSON( the_url_is_here, function( data ) {
// handle data here
}
```

However the browser gives me the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.edmunds.com/api/vehicle/v2/aston-martin/models?state=used&view=basic&fmt=json&api_key=334vr68yy9eb4chec2t4hh7s. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I tried adding the following header: `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'` to the HTTP request based on the information I read online, but the error is the same. There is really not a lot of information online about this, and I am stuck for sometime. Would really appreciate some help.

My application was working perfectly and this happened suddenly.

Comment: use  JSONP instead, JSONP works for me.

Comment: @Dr.Molle Found the solution 10 mins ago, using JSONP. You can add it as an answer though :)